# why the contents are not displaying in center in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am learning react-native and the flexbox layouts don't seem to be consistent. In the code snippet below all I am trying to do is have a divider in the middle of the screen but it always align to the left:

```
<View style={styles.row}>
            <View
              style={{
                flex: 0.8,
                justifyContent:'center',
                borderColor: '#1abc9c',
                borderWidth: 1
              }}
            />
          </View>
</View>

let styles = StyleSheet.create({
row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginHorizontal: 6,
    marginVertical: 6,
  },
});
```

Can somebody please let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<View
    style={{
      flex: 1, // << look at this // Occupy the entire container
      flexDirection: "row",
      marginHorizontal: 6,
      marginVertical: 6,
      justifyContent: "center" // center the children horizontally - 
                               //since flexDirection: 'row'
   }}
  >
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 0.5,
        justifyContent: "center",
        borderColor: "#1abc9c",
        borderWidth: 1
      }}
    />
  </View>
```

Comment: Hi Hend, it is still same layout. aligned to the left.

Comment: Hi ... if you want the divider to be in the middle of the screen then flex: 0.8 has to be flex: 0.5 // occupy 50% of the container

Comment: Even when I set it to 0.5, it spans half of the width of the screen but it is still aligned to the left and not in the center.

Comment: if you want to center the inner View, then take a look at the edited style

Comment: Hend, that is what I used, the edited code you posted. Thanks.

Comment: I added  justifyContent: "center" to the parent View :)

Comment: Thanks Hend. It works now. I was also making a mistake when I set style attribute. I was not using all styles as an array but rather as comma separated styles which caused some of them not to be used.

Comment: Happy coding :)